# Rearranging the logistic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I usually see the logistic function in the form

1. $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

However, I see it is sometimes expressed as

2. $\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}$

Would someone walk me through the algebraic steps to get from 1 to 2?

Comment: Expand the first fraction by $e^x$ (numerator and denominator).

Comment: If it does not occur to you at first to multiply top and bottom by $e^x$, you could equivalently observe that $e^{-x}=\dfrac1{e^x}$, replace your expression with $\dfrac1{1+\frac1{e^x}}$, and proceed to simplify it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that you will not change any expression when multiplying by $1$. Here we will ''choose a $1$'' that looks like 
$$
\dfrac{e^x}{e^x}. 
$$
Then, when we multiply your expression by this choice of $1$ we arrive at:
$$
\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\cdot 1=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \dfrac{e^x}{e^x}.
$$
Multiplication is done as usual to obtain:
$$
\dfrac{e^x}{e^{x}(1+e^{-x})},
$$
which now simplifies to
$$
\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+(e^x e^{-x})}.
$$
Notice that $e^x e^{-x} = 1$, so the denominator really is $e^x + 1 = 1+e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

First, multiply top and bottom of (1) by $e^x$. This cannot change the value of the fraction, so:

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^x e^{-x}}.$$

Now, use the fact that for any numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$. Hence, $e^x e^{-x}=e^{x-x}=e^0=1$. Thus:

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is through multiplication of $\frac{e^x}{e^x}$.

First part $$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by

$$\frac{e^x}{e^x}$$

Then we have 
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\times \frac{e^x}{e^x}$$

$$ \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

We know that $e^x.e^{-x}=1$